# Python authenticated calls to bitfinex exchange

Tags: python, api, bitcoin

I am having some major issues here with making authenticated calls to bitfinex. I have followed the documentation and a few examples but I can not get this working. I keep getting Invalid Signature as the response and its not authenitcating.

Any tips or pointers would be great, I am still learning with python so I am a bit stumped on this one.

Thanks!

```
# pull current offers
def bitfinex_get_offers():
if lend_usd == True:
    payloadObject_usd = {
        'request': '/v1/offers',
        'nonce': str(time.time() * 100000),
        'options': {'symbol': 'USD'}
    }
    usd_offers_payload_json = json.dumps(payloadObject_usd)
    usd_offers_payload = str(base64.b64encode(usd_offers_payload_json))
    usd_offers_payload_encode = hmac.new(api_secret, usd_offers_payload, hashlib.sha384)
    usd_offers_payload_encode = usd_offers_payload_encode.hexdigest()
    headers_usd = {
                'X-BFX-APIKEY': api_key,
                'X-BFX-PAYLOAD': base64.b64encode(usd_offers_payload_json),
                'X-BFX-SIGNATURE': usd_offers_payload_encode
                }

    usd_offers_request = requests.get(offers_url, data={}, headers = headers_usd)
    return usd_offers_request.json()

else:
    payloadObject_btc = {
                    'request': '/v1/offers',
                    'nonce': str(time.time() * 100000),
                    'options': {'symbol': 'BTC'}
                    }
    btc_offers_payload_json = json.dumps(payloadObject_btc)
    btc_offers_payload = str(base64.b64encode(btc_offers_payload_json))
    btc_offers_payload_encode = hmac.new(api_secret, btc_offers_payload, hashlib.sha384)
    btc_offers_payload_encode = btc_offers_payload_encode.hexdigest()
    headers_btc = {
                'X-BFX-APIKEY': api_key,
                'X-BFX-PAYLOAD': base64.b64encode(btc_offers_payload_json),
                'X-BFX-SIGNATURE': btc_offers_payload_encode
                }
    btc_offers_request = requests.get(offers_url, data={}, headers = headers_btc)
    return btc_offers_request.json()


# pull current balances
def bitfinex_get_balance():
payloadObject_balance = {
            'request': '/v1/balances',
            'nonce': str(time.time() * 100000),
            'options': ()
            }
balance_payload_json = json.dumps(payloadObject_balance)
balance_payload = str(base64.b64encode(balance_payload_json))
balance_payload_encode = hmac.new(api_secret, balance_payload, hashlib.sha384)
balance_signature = balance_payload_encode.hexdigest()
headers_balance = {
                'X-BFX-APIKEY': api_key,
                'X-BFX-PAYLOAD': base64.b64encode(balance_payload_json),
                'X-BFX-SIGNATURE': balance_signature
                }
balance_request = requests.get(balance_url, data={}, headers = headers_balance)
print('Response Code: ' + str(balance_request.status_code))
print('Response Header: ' + str(balance_request.headers))
print('Response Content: '+ str(balance_request.content))
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use byte type api_secret.

```
api_secret = "ABCD"     # (X)
api_secret = b"ABCD"    # (O)
```